# File type of a Zip file is changing while copying to AWS S3

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, filestream

I am trying to copy a zipfile from my local machine into AWS S3 bucket. 
I am successfully able to copy the file, however the file type changes to file instead of {.zip}

I am new to AWS and hence not sure if i have to tweak my code in order to copy the zip file as it is without any changes to its file type.

Here is my code :

```
using (var client = GetS3Client())
using (var transferUtility = new TransferUtility(client))
using (var metadataStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var metadata = new StreamWriter(metadataStream))
using (var zipImageStream = new FileStream(zipInfo.FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
var uploadRecordRequest = CreateUploadRequest(zipInfo.ZipFileName, zipImageStream);
transferUtility.Upload(uploadRecordRequest);
}
```

With this i am able to upload a zip file and the file uploaded is as below 
[image]

Hope someone can help guide me in the right direction to fix this.

**Edit 1** :

```
private TransferUtilityUploadRequest CreateUploadRequest(string key, Stream stream)
        {
            return new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
            {
                BucketName = _aWSBucketName,
                Key = key,
                InputStream = stream,
                ServerSideEncryptionMethod = _serverSideEncryptionMethod,
                ServerSideEncryptionKeyManagementServiceKeyId = _serverSideEncryptionKMSKeyId
            };
        }
```

zipInfo object is formed as below

[image]

Comment: Is CreateUploadRequest part of the SDK or a function that you wrote?  If it is the latter, post the code for that please.

Comment: @AshamanKingpin It is a method that i have written. It returns TransferUtilityUploadRequest object. Have updated(Edit 1) my question with what that method is doing.

Comment: Thanks, can you also include how zipInfo is being constructed?

Comment: @AshamanKingpin zipInfo is just an object which has file name and pathinfo etc,Added the object in question

Comment: Why have you stripped the .zip extension from zipinfo.ZipFileName? And it probably doesn't matter for the downloaded file (unless you're clicking 'Open file' not 'Save file') but you're not setting ContentType="application/zip" for the upload either in the TransferUtilityUploadRequest.

Comment: But there is your problem, you are using zipInfo.ZipFileName as the key for your object and the value of that attribute is test_sampe_zip instead of test_sample.zip.  If you are only copying zip files, then do something like this ... CreateUploadRequest(zipInfo.ZipFileName + ".zip", zipImageStream);

Comment: @Rup adding the .zip extension(hardcoding) has solved my problem. But however ZipFIleName is the value that i get from a different application which i cannot control. Adding just contentType="Application/zip" has not solved my problem either. So looks like i have to hardcode ".zip" to the file name.

Comment: Setting the content data is correct though, and there's no harm in getting it right. (Although if I were Amazon I'd try and guess it from the file if it's not provided, so I expect it'll get set right anyway.) That said it won't help when you've saved the file to disk on Windows and tried to open it from there: the case it might solve is if you click the link and you click 'open' rather than 'download'.

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the help, is there any way that i can just 'copy' the file to AWS instead of uploading the file in bytes?(Which i believe would take way more time than just doing a 'copy & paste')

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with what you're doing, assuming the file is small enough it'll comfortably fit in your PC's memory (and assuming this is a file you have locally and you're not e.g. copying it from one remote server to S3). If you search for "S3 explorer" or "S3 browser" then there are third-party UIs that you can probably just copy & paste files into, but they'll be doing the same upload behind the scenes.

Comment: @Rup Ok, The file can go upto the size of 5GB. And no i will not be having the file locally in my machine, the file resides in our server and will have to transfer it to S3 which will be in a different domain(Client's server).